# RTSP Audio Clicks/Pops/Peaks/glitches and ticks. (iPhone Streaming) Any advice?

Tags: iphone, rtsp, rtp, wma, asf

I'm using some code related to RTSP, RTP to listen to various RTSP Streams Using FFMPEG, it works!

BUT

The noise is being decoded in such a way that every 10 seconds a glitch in the ASF decoding of the stream occurs, where the Volume Peaks and makes a loud Popping sound.

Generally the sound you hear when a packet is corrupted...

I'm just wondering if anyone can help me with where to look for Troubleshooting, when working with WMA ASF Audio Streams.

Any help/tips/pointers are appreciated.

I'm not sure if it's in the RTSP Parser, Data Buffer, WMA Decoder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about WMA/ASF, but have you checked the sequence numbers in the RTP headers are contiguous (how you would find out what these are will depend on what RTSP/RTP library you are using)?  At least then you will know whether packets are going missing or not.